# Convert 1000 months in 83 years and 4 months

Tags: c#, datetime

I try to make something and its work, but when I try to make a date under 1 month its crash. Can someone help me? The code is like this:

```
int page = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int campingDays = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int pagesPerDay = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

int months = page / ((30 - campingDays) * pagesPerDay);
int years = months / 12;
int remainingMonths = months % 12;

Console.WriteLine("{0} years {1} months", years, remainingMonths);
```

Comment: What do you mean by _it crash_? What exception or error message you get? And what is your inputs?

Comment: apparently [it works](http://ideone.com/zo3oA0)

Comment: Its shows me the "divide by zero" error. Other time i press 10, 5, 100 and it must write 0 years 1 months, but it says 0 years 0 months.

Comment: It looks like it's some kind of homework. Can you also add a description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Michal Ciechan is correct. (Just read your answer closely)

suggestion:

```
int _campingDaysAdj = 30 - campingDays;
if(_campingDaysAdj > 0 && pagesPerDay > 0)
{
    int months = page / ((30 - campingDays) * pagesPerDay);
    int years = months / 12;
    int remainingMonths = months % 12;

    Console.WriteLine("{0} years {1} months", years, remainingMonths);
}
else
{
    //throw an exception or an error message etc.
}
```

Comment: 30 camping days looks like a valid value. You should handle this situation differently.

Comment: yes, this i better. I just getting home from exam and this was one of the problems. thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's how i solve the "0 years 1 months" problem. There you go!

```
    int readedPages = (30 - campingDays) * regularDays;

    if ((campingDays == 30) || (regularDays == 0))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("never");
    }
    else
    {
        double readDuration = Math.Ceiling(bookPages / (double)readedPages);
        double years = (int)(readDuration / 12);
        double remainingMonths =(readDuration % 12);
        Console.WriteLine("{0} years {1} months", years, remainingMonths);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You would get divide by zero error whenever

- `campingDays` is 30 because of `(30 - campingDays)`
- `pagesPerDay` is - 0

The problematic line:

```
int months = page / ((30 - campingDays) * pagesPerDay);
```

You may want 2 `if` statements to handle those cases.

Comment: Yes, i know but where to put this "iff" i try few times but its get worst :/

Comment: what is the meaning of page Variable? Why do you need it? What do you use it for?